# How to get all images from a website using crawler4J

Tags: java, image, web-crawler, crawler4j

I want to create a program in java that gets all the images from a website that requires login information using a web crawler. I know this is possible using the image crawler example in crawler4J: https://github.com/yasserg/crawler4j/tree/master/crawler4j-examples/crawler4j-examples-base/src/test/java/edu/uci/ics/crawler4j/examples/imagecrawler. But i dont know how to configure it so that it uses my credentials to login in the page.
I've already tried using:

```
    String formUsername = "myUsername";
    String formPassword = "myPassword";
    String urlLogin = "myWebsite.xxx";
    String session_user = "Login";
    String session_password = "Password";

    AuthInfo authInfo = new FormAuthInfo(formUsername, formPassword, urlLogin, session_user, session_password );

    config.addAuthInfo(authInfo);
```

However this doesn't seem to work. I could really use some help in this. Thank you

Comment: This depends completely on the mechanism used by the target website for authentication, i.e. does your code provide the authentication parameters in the format expected by the website.  Since you have not shared those details, the question is not answerable in its present form.

Comment: @JimGarrison   Thanks for responding, how do i know which are the authentication parameters expected by the website ?.